# Can I use the 'object' keyword to make a method more generic?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a method that writes myEvent to a json file provided by the path parameter.

Instead of overloading this method and having one method that takes MyEventObject as the first parameter and a second overloaded method with `List<MyEventObject>` as the first parameter I am wondering if I could just use a generic "object" as the first parameter?

The code inside the method is literally the exact same code whether it is a list or just a single object of MyEventObject. The code works, but I am wondering if this is the best way to do this for my simple method and what the best practice is for accomplishing something like this in C#.

```
private void WriteEventsToFile(object myEvent, string path)
{
    string eventObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent);
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, eventObject);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("System.IO.File.WriteAllText Exception : " + e.Message + "\nCall Stack : " + e.StackTrace);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix rethrowing: `throw e;` must be `throw;`

Comment: To clarify the comment above: `throw;` re-throws the current exception *unchanged*.  `throw e;` re-throws the current exception but *resets the stack trace of the exception to the current stack trace*.  There are times when that is the right thing to do, but most of the time you want to maintain the original stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @EricLippert ah ok thanks for the clarification. I will change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Instead of overloading this method and having one method that takes `MyEventObject` as the first parameter and a second overloaded method with `List<MyEventObject>` as the first parameter I am wondering if I could just use a generic "object" as the first parameter?

You could. It's a bad idea. Don't do it.

A method which takes `object` means **I can accept any object**.  If you can only accept two kinds of things then *write two methods*.

If the method is very short, like this one, then just repeat yourself.

Barely acceptable: if the method is very long and you want to not repeat yourself then make a private helper method that takes object, and *asserts its preconditions*:

```
public void WriteEventsToFile(MyEventObject myEvent, string path)
{
  WriteEventsToFileHelper(myEvent, path);
}
public void WriteEventsToFile(List<MyEventObject> myEvent, string path)
{
  WriteEventsToFileHelper(myEvent, path);
}
private void WriteEventsToFileHelper(object myEvent, string path) 
{
  Debug.Assert(myEvent is MyEventObject || myEvent is List<MyEventObject>);
  ...
```

But that's kinda gross; I would do that only if I really felt there was no other way.

The type system is your friend and it is there to keep you safe and healthy. Use it!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. I try really hard not to have repetitive code, but you make a good case for doing so in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your approach:

- The file will be different if you write a list of events or a single event.
- It might be a bit confusing when you're using the API - what is expected here?

I suggest solving both like this:

```
private void WriteEventsToFile(MyEventObject myEvent, string path) {
    WriteEventsToFile(new[] {myEvent}, path);
}
private void WriteEventsToFile(ICollection<MyEventObject> myEvents, string path)
{
    string eventObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvents);
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, eventObject);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("System.IO.File.WriteAllText Exception : " + e.Message + "\nCall Stack : " + e.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I write a List of events using Json.NET then the file is just an array of Json objects.

When pulling the file back into a List< MyEventObject > using Json.NET it doesn't matter if it was just one event in the file or an array of events I can still put the data into a List object.

So it only seems to make a difference with writing to the file and not when reading from it, and sometimes I have multiple events to write and sometimes just one.

You're right it is a little bit confusing. I thought just having one method to call would help make it less confusing. Thanks for the help!